# How do I set an alias for a search command that takes two arguments

Tags: linux, search, alias, command-line-arguments

I have a shell command which find files that contain 2 strings together:

```
$ grep -rl JFL . 2>/de/null | while read n; do grep -l 20120907 "$n"; done
```

The strings above are `JFL` and `20120907`

Now I would like to set it as an alias, like below:

```
mysearch JFL 20120907
```

How can I create this alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to your `~./bashrc` the following:

```
mysearch () {
      grep -rl "$1" . 2>/dev/null | while read n; do grep -l "$2" "$n"; done
}
```

This defines the function that became available as a command at the `bash` prompt. All arguments to the `functions` in bash are expanded as `$1`, `$2`,... like arguments to the scripts. When editing your `.bashrc` do not forget to restart bash (re-login), as bash read this file when it starts.

Comment: Functions are far better than aliases on several different levels.  Listen to Serge and you'll go far.